# Download file from Skydrive using SkyDrive Live

Tags: windows-phone-7, onedrive

I'm using SkyDrive Live to upload files, but now I want to download the file I just uploaded.  In the documentation it mentions a file ID but I'm not finding how I can get that ID.

I have a folder that I placed the file into so I would somehow need to pass the folder ID and then get the fileID...

Does anyone know how to do this or know of any tutorials on this?

Comment: can you please help how to upload files from wp7 to skydrive ?

Answer (score 4):

If you uploaded the file with SkyDrive SDK, then you get the fileId by the UploadCompleted event's e.Result["id"]

If you have the folderId, but not the fileId, then you can query the content of the folder with client.GetAsync(folderId/files). The GetCompleted event's e.Result["data"] returns a IDictionary of file descriptions, each containing the fileId. In this cased you need to identify the required file by dictionaryEntry["name"] or some other magic..